# How to make a background macOS application?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to develop a macOS app that performs operations on a file when the user chooses to do so. My goal is to let a user right-click a file, select my app from the list of services so that the app will pop open a UI with things like configuration options, etc.

A prime example would be Evernote's "Add to Evernote"; when a user clicks it, the Evernote app opens and saves the file there. In addition, I need to switch control to the UI, so that the user can input some settings, before performing any file operations.

The place where I'm stuck now is how to get the app/UI open when the user clicks it from the contextual menu, as well as keeping the UI hidden initially. From some googling, I think what I need to make is an agent? I'm not really sure.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1

Comment: @jtbandes thanks for pointing that out! that's close to what i need..what i'm missing is a way to switch control to the app, after selecting the service and before performing file operations